# UIPanGestureRecognizer returns null on an iPhone 6, but not on any other device

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin

I'm having an issue with UIPanGestureRecognizer on an iPhone 6. The following code runs well on an iPhone 5 and on the iOS simulator:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer panGesture = new UIPanGestureRecognizer ((pg) => { Console.WriteLine(pg.State); });
```

On an iPhone 6 that I have, pg is null when the gesture starts.

I have no idea why. I tried deleting the app, reinstalling it, rebooting the device.

The iPhone 6 runs iOS 8.3 (12F70), as well as the iPhone 5.

Comment: Try resetting your device..

Comment: Also don't use Xamarin, native all the way.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by resetting the device? I just tried the code on an iPhone 6 plus and I get the same error, pg is null. Im completely lost. Thank you.